# Using py2exe to compile script using zmq

Tags: python, python-2.7, zeromq, py2exe

I have a python 2.7 script that uses zmq and am trying to build a windows executable for it using py2exe. I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "console.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "zmq\__init__.pyc", line 34, in <module>
  File "zmq\backend\__init__.pyc", line 40, in <module>
  File "zmq\backend\__init__.pyc", line 27, in <module>
  File "zmq\backend\select.pyc", line 26, in select_backend
ImportError: No module named cython
```

I have tried py2exe `--includes` option, including cython and zmq with no success. I have also tried running the script with `-O` option and copying the resulting `.pyo` files to my dist directory. What am I missing?

Comment: How did u solve?

Comment: Don't think I did, ended up just bundling the python scripts

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick in my setup.py

```
import zmq.libzmq
setup(\
    version='0.0.1',
    options = {'py2exe' : {
        'includes': [ 'zmq.backend.cython'],
        "optimize": 2,
        'packages': 'encodings'
    },
    },
    data_files=[
        ('lib', (zmq.libzmq.__file__,))
    ],
    console=['app.py'],
    scripts = [ "app.py","file1.py","file2.py","file3.cfg"],
    zipfile = 'None',
)
```

Hope it helps someone.